# Почему источник 'undef' не заменяется на источник 'other'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дана задача с исходными данными:

```
import pandas as pd
logs = pd.read_csv('/datasets/logs.csv')
logs['email'] = logs['email'].fillna(value='')

logs.loc[logs['source'] == 'None', 'source'] = 'email'

logs_grouped = logs.groupby('source').agg({'purchase': ['count', 'sum']})
logs_grouped['conversion'] = logs_grouped['purchase']['sum'] / logs_grouped['purchase']['count']
```

---

Необходимо:
объединить (с помощью замены значения источника) источник 'undef' c 'other' и подсчитать конверсию после замены 'undef' на 'other'.

```
logs.loc[logs['source'] == 'undef', 'source'] == 'other'

logs_grouped = logs.groupby('source').agg({'purchase': ['count', 'sum']})
logs_grouped['conversion'] = logs_grouped['purchase']['sum'] / logs_grouped['purchase']['count']
print(logs_grouped)
```

Почему источник 'undef' не заменяется на источник 'other'?

Comment: А как вы определяете что он не заменяется? Что выдает: `(logs['source'] == 'undef').sum()`?

Comment: 2. (logs['source'] == 'undef').sum() выдает 181

Comment: это после замены??

Comment: 1. Определяю через: ошибку, на которую мне указывают (Заполните пустые значения переменной source и замените значения undef), т.е. фактически замена не была произведена; print не показывает фактическую замену.

Comment: Да, после logs.loc[logs['source'] == 'undef', 'source'] == 'other'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что вместо присваивания вы делаете сравнение:

```
logs.loc[logs['source'] == 'undef', 'source'] == 'other'
#  NOTE: -----------------------------------> ^^
```

---

Пример исходного DataFrame:

```
In [75]: df
Out[75]:
  source  purchase
0   None         1
1  undef         3
2    aaa         2
3    bbb         4
4    aaa         3
5  undef         1
6   None         2
```

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
In [76]: mapping = {"None":"email", "undef":"other"}

In [77]: df["source"] = df["source"].replace(mapping)
```

Результат:

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
  source  purchase
0  email         1
1  other         3
2    aaa         2
3    bbb         4
4    aaa         3
5  other         1
6  email         2
```

Кроме того `ser.sum() / ser.count()` лучше заменить на `ser.mean()`:

```
In [79]: df.groupby("source")["purchase"].mean()
Out[79]:
source
aaa      2.5
bbb      4.0
email    1.5
other    2.0
Name: purchase, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Благодарю, получилось.